# How to detect a message from a specific user and delete it

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to detect a message from a specific user (me), delete it and send the same message again.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
if message.author.id == 881583268569436200:
    await message.delete(message)
    await client.process_commands(message)
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Please help

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use `await message.delete(message)` you already got the message after `await` statement. Just use `await message.delete()`.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.id == 881583268569436200:
        msg = message.content
        await message.delete()
        await message.channel.send(msg)

    await client.process_commands(message)
```